# Part identification

Tags: part-identification

Can you help me identify which part numbers these parts are? I can't find them on Lego's site or on brickset.com:

[image: parts1-3]
[image: part4]
[image: part5]

**Edit:**

I've found the two dark grey bricks in the left photo, so that just leaves the yellow one, and the other two photos.

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the yellow part is listed on BrickSet as "[Lamp Holder](http://brickset.com/parts/408124)" or "[Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip Light - Thick Ring](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4081b)", 4081 on BrickLink, Peeron, etc.

The light grey piece is from the Flick Missiles, and is listed on Brickset as "[3 M.Arch W.Knob And Shaft Ø¸3.2](http://brickset.com/parts/4520320)" or "Technic, Pin 1/2 with 2L Bar Extension (Flick Missile)", 61184.

The final piece is "[Mini Fig. Back Palte W. Knob](http://brickset.com/parts/4210469)" or "Minifig, Neck Bracket with Back Stud", 42446

For completeness, the other two are:

"[Angular Plate 1.5 Bot. 1X2 1/2](http://brickset.com/parts/6000606)" on Brickset or "Bracket 1 x 2 - 1 x 2 Inverted", 99780

The tile I couldn't find on Brickset other than in Rebrickable inventories where it's listed as "Tile 1 x 2 with Joystick and Vehicle Control Panel Pattern" (3069bpr0090) or on BrickLink as "Tile 1 x 2 with Vehicle Control Panel Pattern", 3069bpc1